# Is it possible to debounce d3.zoom callback?

Tags: d3.js, underscore.js

I tried to create a zoom event with a function that redraws my svg.  It was not running smoothly, and I would like to debounce it using the underscore library.  i have imported underscore, but now if I call the redraw function, nothing happens.

This works:

```
let zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent(scaleExtent)
    .on("zoom", redraw);
function redraw(){
  console.log('test') //test
}
```

This doesn't:

```
let zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent(scaleExtent)
    .on("zoom", _.debounce(redraw,200));

function redraw(){
  console.log('test') // --no output--
}
```

Any thoughts on what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your working code?

Comment: I edited to show a skeleton function to be called on zoom.  It's not being called when wrapped in debounce...no console output.

Comment: I meant full code, so we can see why its not running :)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have not posted the full code but here is how you can use underscore `debounce` and zoom.

I have put in comments in the code.

```js
 //save instance of transform
 var transform;
 var svg = d3.select("body")
   .append("svg")
   .attr("width", "100%")
   .attr("height", "100%")
   .call(d3.zoom().on("zoom", function() {
     //save instance of transform, because when debouce is called
     //d3.event will be null
     transform = d3.event.transform;
     //call the debounse function
     lazyzoom();
   }))
   .append("g")

 svg.append("circle")
   .attr("cx", 100)
   .attr("cy", 100)
   .attr("r", 50)
   .style("fill", "red")

 var lazyzoom = _.debounce(function() {
   
   svg.attr("transform", transform)
 }, 300);
```

```css
      body,
      html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
      
      svg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
      
      p {
        text-align: center;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
```